# Strange MySQL order in ID

Tags: mysql

I have id with auto increment. Using Navicat I've inserted an row, as I do always. The 20th id was inserted before 19. Like 17, 18, 20, 19, and then they are normal 21, 22, 23 etc. How I can move that 20 after 19?

Comment: You probably have some other column currently sorting in Navicat.  The records themselves are not out of order (they don't really have a defined order unless you specify one when querying)

Comment: What do you mean move? just order by id and it will be ordered.

Comment: @Michael, they are sorted like this in my all PHP outputs.

Comment: @george Then the query engine is choosing a different column as the default sort when you query with PHP. If you need them ordered by id, add `ORDER BY id` to your query.  MySQL database rows are not sorted in any way in particular until you specify a sort order.

Comment: @Michael, But I don't use PHP to look to my table, I use Navicat to browse.

Comment: Whatever, I'll do it manually by editing the MySQL table, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify an `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT` query, there is no guarantee that you will get rows in the correct order. Instead, try something like `SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY id`.

Comment: Just because it wasn't the answer you were hoping for, doesn't mean that it isn't the right answer. See [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?467755-How-does-MySQL-order-records-with-no-ORDER-BY) for more information on a similar question.